# Powershell - Output individual members of an array of objects in a pipeline

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm not sure if the title is correct. And I know this is easily answered and is probably all over the internet. But, I need your help please.

If I run a powershell command that returns multiple objects, and each object has it's own members, with one of those members being another list of multiple objects, what is the most efficient way to output this cleanly to the screen?

For instance, see the following command for querying MFA authentication methods a user has chosen in Office 365:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $null} | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName, StrongAuthenticationMethods
```

The output is:

```
UserPrincipalName                  StrongAuthenticationMethods
-----------------                  ---------------------------
user1@domain.com       {Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod, Microsoft.Online.Adm...
user2@domain.com       {Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod, Microsoft.Online.Adm...
user3@domain.com       {Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod, Microsoft.Online.Adm...
```

I want to list the UserPrincipalName followed by the value of the `MethodType` member of each StrongAuthenticationMethods object in a single line of code.

Take it easy on me, I know this has an obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to unroll the inner collection and output one for each object in the outer collection; example (not tested):

```
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object { $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods } | ForEach-Object {
  $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName
  $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
      "UserPrincpalName"            = $upn
      "StrongAuthenticationMethods" = $_
    }
  }
```